# What is Muraqabah?

Tags: sufism

What is Muraqabah?

What are the stages of Muraqabah?

I know Muraqabah is like meditation and the word means to watch over or take care.  I know that metaphorically it means that through this kind of meditation a person can watch over or take care of his soul, and gain knowledge of it and it's surroundings and Creator.  I want to know more about what muraqabah is.  I have also heard that in the Sufi view of muraqabah, it is divided into "stages"; why is this, and what are these stages?

Comment: Have you seen the wikipage on Muraqabah? Wasn't it useful? I assume it lay outs the Sufi formulation of Muraqaba. What I've personally read on the topic from my own preferred sources vary greatly from that formulation. Would you be interested in a formulation by Shiite scholars of mysticism?

Comment: @infatuated yes I would be very interested, if it answers the question.  Please also provide your sources so one can do further research if one wanted to. :)

Comment: Oh sure, but it takes a good amount of time. I will have to brush up on my sources and take notes and share the summary. It's worth the effort though as it is a very interesting and beneficial topic.

Comment: [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muraqaba) ....

Answer (score 1):

Assalam-O-Alaykoum

Al-Muraqabah is divided into stages to help understand its aims, because it's linked more into soul than body it is little bit hard to be determined and understood by words, Al-Muraqabah is the Meditation of Sufi's it has three stages and these three stages are divided into 3 sub-stages, so in total we have nine, but honestly now am going to describe half of the answer because i don't know them all, it starts by :

1 - Monitoring Allah presence to walk to him constantly :

- Maximizing the value of Allah in the heart till you trivialize any thing great but         Allah.
- Oncoming that bears you to continuously walk to Allah with veneration.
- The happiness that leads to completing the walk to Allah with a continuous good work (the sweetness of Faith).

2 - Monitoring the perception of Allah to you :

- The rejection of disobeying Allah orders, tellings and willings.
- Regretting Objection to his names, his character and his doings.
- Everything you see is from Allah as an incident or a creation.

this is all what i know about the subject, i honestly , missed the last stage.

Hope it helped, Allah knows better.

Answer (score 0):

Muraqabah is an Arabic word. It is translated in English as meditation. It's a spiritual exercise to increase the love of Allah and to abstain from the disobedience of Allah. Just as physical diseases are cured by medicine, the spiritual diseases are cured by spiritual medicine and Muraqabah is one type of spiritual medicine.

For example, in Naqsbandi Sufi order the first lesson is the muraqabah on the qalb (spiritual heart which lies two fingers below the left chest ). Zikr on qalb eliminates the disease of lust from the salik. After that there is second lesson which eliminates the disease of anger.

Note: Most of the information is based on my own personal experience with my teacher(shaykh)  Shaykh Zulfiqar Ahmad Naqsbandi. He is one of the leading Sufi of the current era. He had written many books and delivered numerous lectures on sufism.

Refrences:
http://www.tasawwuf.org/basics/muraqabah.html
http://suluk.com/en/basics-for-the-seeker/

Answer (score -2):

Procedure of Maraqbah

1. Go to Dark Room
2. Sit relax & Close Your Eyes
3. Down Your Head
4. Now Start thinking your heart is saying ALLAH ALLAH ALLAH

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE, Please go through [How to write a good answer](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Specifically try to back up your question with some sources.